# Row spaces question

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose **S** is a six-dimensional subspace of nine-dimensional space **R^9**.
What is the smallest possible size of a matrix **A** that has row space **S**?

The answer is a 6 x 9 matrix. Why not 6 x 6? Or even 6 x 1? There are three "extra" rows in **S**(all consisting 0) after all. Or have I misunderstood the question? Is the matrix **A** supposed to have a row space that matches the column space of **S**?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb R^6$ is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^9$.  It is not even a sub*set*.  Yes, there is a subspace of $\Bbb R^9$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^6$, but that is not the same thing.  If $A$ has row space which is a subspace of $\Bbb R^9$ it is thus required that the rows are themselves elements of $\Bbb R^9$ and thus have nine entries per row.

Comment: "*...that matches the column space of $S$?*"  $S$ is not a matrix.  $S$ does not *have* a column space.

Comment: @nailclipper What do you mean by "rows in **S**"? As the other commenter notes, **S** is not a matrix

Comment: @JMoravitz Apologies, I overlooked that. Here's my thought process now. If **S** is a six-dimensional subspace, the rows of **A** must have 6 independent rows(so that there are 6 basis vectors, that match the dimension). Thus 6 rows. However, I don't see why there must be 9 columns?

Comment: Again... you need $9$ columns so that the rows live in $\Bbb R^9$ and can be thought of spanning a subspace of $\Bbb R^9$.  If there were some other number, like $7$ then they would have been elements of $\Bbb R^7$ instead, not $\Bbb R^9$